# How to add protected route in Next.js using jwt token received from custom backend?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jwt, next.js, frontend

I am building a full-stack app with NestJS for the backend and Next.js for the frontend. I have added stateless authentication in NestJS using jwt and passport. Now, I want to add protected route in my Next.js app based on the authenticity of the jwt token that I received from my NestJS backend. What is the best way to achieve this? I want to add protected route for both server-side rendered and client-side rendered pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The term 'protected route' refers to being authorized to access certain resources from certain routes (or GraphQL resolvers), so these routes on the server (NestJS) need to check whether the JWT-token is valid and return an appropriate HTTP response. NestJS has [built in Guards](https://docs.nestjs.com/security/authentication#implement-protected-route-and-jwt-strategy-guards) for that purpose, which return an 401-Unauthorized response in case the JWT is invalid.

So for client-side rendering, if you fetch these resources on your NextJS front-end and include the JWT in the request headers like this: `Authorization: Bearer [token]`, you will know from the HTTP response whether the fetch was successful or not, which will let you either display the data or an error on the front-end.

A simple example for server-side rendering with getServerSideProps could worklike this:

- After you Signin via your NestJS server, you set the JWT in a [cookie](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/cookies) which will be included in every request you make to your NextJS server (its a different server than your NestJS server if you host your NextJS app on vercel)
- In getServerSideProps you parse the cookie (on the NextJS server) and add the parsed token to the headers of the request to your NestJS route.

  ```
    const Component = ({data, authorized}) => {
       return {authorized ? <div>Page Content</div> : <div>Log In to view this content</div>}
     }

     // this function gets called on the NextJS server whenever you visit a page. 
     // If you're logged in and have a cookie, the cookie will be inside context.req.headers.cookie
     export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
            // assuming you use the 'cookie' npm package
           // and you did not sign the cookie on NestJS with a secret so it has a raw value
            const cookies = cookie.parse(context.req.headers.cookie)

            const token = cookies.token // assuming you named the cookie 'token' when you set it on your NestJS server

            // assuming you use the 'axios' npm package
            const response = await axios.get("NestJsServerUrl/route",   
                        headers: {
                         'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`
                         } )
            const authorized = response.status != 401
            return {
                  props: { 
                    data: response.data
                    authorized
                  }
               }
     }
  ```

Now if you're signed in and you have a cookie with the name 'token' containing a valid token in your browser, your browser will first make a request to the NextJS server with that cookie. This cookie will be extracted and parsed in getServerSideProps on the NextJS server, and will then be used to fetch the resources on the NestJS server by adding it to the Authorization header. Based on the response, the NextJS server will render the page by using conditional rendering.

Let me know if it works.

Comment: With Next 12 this functionality can be done more performant using middleware on the edge, which will reduce the loading time by a ton, considering all the fetching performed in getServerSideProps will be blocking the request. Here's an [example](https://github.com/vercel/examples/tree/main/edge-functions/clerk-authentication) with a proof of concept that can also be applied to front-end routes and other auth methods